# Tab Control Edit in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is, in WPF I've created a Tab control and increased the size of tabs according to my requirement.

Now I'm getting the problem. When I increased the size, there is a line behind the tabs up to the corner of WPF.

I want to remove that line and use that space as well for displaying other labels.

How can I achieve that?

[image: Here is the image of my tab view.]

Here is my XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="GitMonitor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GitMonitor"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="992">
        <TabItem x:Name="MyDashboardTab" Header="My Dashboard" Margin="-2,-2,-2,-15">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,11,0,0"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="UntrackedReposTab" Header="Untracked Repositories" Margin="-2,-2,-2,-15">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,11,0,0"/>
        </TabItem>
        
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Remove the custom `Margin=""` properties, they don't work the way I think you expect them to work.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend *against* using the XAML visual designer - you should write XAML by hand. The reason is that it's impossible for a visual-design tool to understand your design *intent* simply by adjusting resize handles - the visual designer is also not sophisticated enough to let you create layouts using `<StackPanel>` using implicit actions.

Comment: ohh, okay. thanks for reply @dai

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
     <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="992" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    </TabControl>
```

If you don't want to write code, go into properties. Select Brush -> BorderBrush and "nobrush" in it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it now.!

Comment: If you got the answer you need then please vote this as your answer.